# Extract data using BeautifulSoup, returning NoneType

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

When using `soup.find` to extract table data, the variable table returns a NoneType. The error is: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'. The class name from the website is shown below in the picture, so it is not like I am using the incorrect class name. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.wunderground.com/history/monthly/KATL/date/2019-12"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.find("table",{"class":"days ng-star-inserted"})
table_body = table.find('tbody')
```

[image: Developer Tools Inspector]

Comment: Did you check if the class is also present in the HTML which is returned by requests?

Comment: Alright, it seems like the table is indeed created dynamically. I believe that this is the request which returns the data: `https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KATL:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20191201&endDate=20191231`.

Answer (score 3):

Requests returns the page's source code "as-is": It does not execute any JavaScript, amongst other things. The table in that page is created dynamically by a script which makes an API call for the data, which means when BeautifulSoup parses the HTML that table simply isn't there yet. When I checked, the exact request which got the data was `https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KATL:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey=6532d6454b8aa370768e63d6ba5a832e&units=e&startDate=20191201&endDate=20191231`.

There are two typical solutions to this: The first, the ideal solution, is to find the API calls/requests that the page uses to grab the data, and replicate those yourself. The second is to programmatically control a browser (or replicate its functionality), which people often do using Selenium.

Luckily for you, that website appears to offer an API. Of course this isn't great if your goal was just to learn web scraping.

Answer (score 1):

The data is retrieved dynamically from an API call you can find in the network tab. The API key can be extracted from either of several js source files - required additional request. You need to convert to EST and then calculate max, min, average with groupby. Example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
import re

def get_api_key():
    r = requests.get('https://www.wunderground.com/bundle-next/6-es2015.002cd6130a78daeda544.js')
    p = re.compile(r'sunApiKey:"(.*?)"')
    api_key = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    return api_key

def get_est_localtime(timestamp):
    utc_dt =  utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp))
    est_dt = utc_dt.astimezone(est_tz)
    return est_dt

utc = pytz.utc
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
est_tz = timezone('US/Eastern')
api_key = get_api_key()
r = requests.get(f'https://api.weather.com/v1/location/KATL:9:US/observations/historical.json?apiKey={api_key}&units=e&startDate=20191201&endDate=20191231')
df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['observations'])
df['valid_time_gmt'] = df['valid_time_gmt'].map(lambda x: get_est_localtime(x).strftime(fmt))
df = df.groupby(by='valid_time_gmt').agg([min, max, np.mean])
print(df['temp'])
```

References:

1. [pytz](http://%20http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)
2. [agg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276301/max-and-min-value-for-each-colum-of-one-dataframe) by @MightyCurious
3. [pandas agg](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)